# What attribute to set on element in Ionic project so it can be seen as content-desc in Appium

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, appium, android-uiautomator

I'm a frontend developer and was asked by automation developers to put some additional attribute on buttons/inputs so they would be able to find that element with their tools.

I wanna set the content-desc attribute for them but don't know which one to place into my HTML.

I've already tried accessibility-id, content-desc, aria-label, role, data-test-id and none of them is ok.